# Weird behaviour of some specific Windows locales: why, and how to cope?

Tags: c++, windows, locale

I wrote a simple C++ program to test available Windows locales.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <locale>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    const char* locName = (argc < 2) ? "" : argv[1];

    std::locale loc (locName);
    std::cout.imbue(loc);

    std::cout << "Locale is " << loc.name() << '\n';
    std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(8);
    std::cout << 12345654321 <<'\n';
    std::cout << 123456.54321 << '\n';;

    return 0;
}
```

I compiled it with msvc19. Here are some test results:

```
c:\Temp>.\test
Locale is
12,345,654,321
123,456.54321000

c:\Temp>.\test C
Locale is C
12345654321
123456.54321000
```

So far so good.

```
c:\Temp>.\test xx_xx
Locale is xx_xx
12,345,654,321
123,456.54321000

c:\Temp>.\test xxx_xxx

c:\Temp>
```

Locale `xx_xx` does not exist, neither does `xxx_xxx`, but one is giving the same results as the default locale, and the other freezes the stream. OK, some more tests...

```
c:\Temp>.\test en_us
Locale is en_us
12,345,654,321
123,456.54321000

c:\Temp>.\test de_de
Locale is de_de
12.345.654.321
123.456,54321000

c:\Temp>
```

Perfect, as it should be. But...

```
c:\Temp>.\test fr_fr
Locale is fr_fr
12345654321
c:\Temp>.\test fre_fr
Locale is fre_fr
12,345,654,321
123,456.54321000

c:\Temp>
```

What? `fr_fr` won't print floating point numbers at all, but `fre_fr` will (albeit with the roles of `,` and `.` apparently reversed). However they are supposed to be aliases of the same locale!

```
c:\Temp> python
>>> import locale
>>> locale.normalize('fr_fr')
'fr_FR.ISO8859-1'
>>> locale.normalize('fre_fr')
'fr_FR.ISO8859-1'
```

Hmm...

```
c:\Temp>.\test fr_FR.ISO8859-1

c:\Temp>
```

No output at all.

Now I have read somewhere that one cannot use the encoding suffix in setting C or C++ locales. I can understand that (although it's annoying as hell). But why the weird behaviour of `fr_fr` (and `fr` and `french` and `fr_FR` and `French_France`) and how can I recognise and avoid such defective locales ahead of time? Interestingly, `fr_be` and `fr_lu` behave as expected.

Comment: The pattern per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/setlocale-wsetlocale?view=msvc-160) is `"<language>_<country>.<code_page>"` with an exception for `.utf8` and `C`

Comment: I'm getting this output with `fr_FR`: `12á345á654á321
123á456,54321000` -- maybe French uses some non-ASCII characters for their thousands-separator, and maybe that messes with console output since your program isn't using `wchar_t` for output. Try using the wide string output functions, maybe that's better. Or maybe just output to a stringstream and look at that in a reliable debugger... Or a file...

Comment: I was expecting an exception for `Locale is xx_xx` see _"...3,5) std::runtime_error if the operating system has no locale named std_name..."_ https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/locale/locale

Comment: @RichardCritten confirmed [MS has no documented deviation behavior on that](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/locale-class?view=msvc-160)

Comment: @Mgetz MS affirms the exception "_..If locale name locale_name is a null pointer or otherwise invalid, the function throws runtime_error...."_ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/locale-class?view=msvc-160#locale

Comment: @RichardCritten which was my point [however...](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/issues/1033) indicates this may be an issue. I figured I'd check as sometimes MS has deviations from standard

Comment: @Mgetz Documentation is fine and dandy, but nothing with `.<code_page>` seems to be ever working.

Comment: @dialer that's interesting, maybe my terminal is set up incorrectly.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. see the link to the defect on their repo. It seems they aren't properly doing error handling in some cases. You're almost better doing `setlocale` directly and checking the return... then setting `std::locale`

Comment: Locales in C++ are broken beyond any hope. They will eventually have to get deprecated and die in flames. I wouldn't invest any time into what will eventually become a liability. It is not without precedent that things get removed from C++ without a replacement. Stick to the locale services provided by the platform and thank yourself for that decision a few years down the road.

Comment: @IInspectable No, locales *on Windows* are broken. Locales in C++ are just fine.

Comment: @n.1 Locales on Windows work just fine. It's the C++ implementation that doesn't. Hardly surprising, given that there isn't even a standard notion of character encodings in C++. If you've been following C++ you surely must have seen its failure in coming up with something that resembles a locale. Like, how `std::moneypunct` is broken and cannot be fixed. Or the time when `std::codecvt` went down the tubes? It's accepted that [the locale actively hinder the localization effort](https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/f47x4o/202002_prague_iso_c_committee_trip_report_c20_is/fhoy1sq/?context=3).

Comment: @IInspectable Everything I wrote about is observable in C with plain old `setlocale`, so if anything about C++ locales specifically is more broken than locale services provided by the platform, it must be some other thing. Everything in and around encoding support is broken indeed, but bundling  encodings with locales was a tragic error in the first place. They have nothing to do with each other and should be divorced, by force if needed.

Comment: @n.1 Windows exposes an API that isn't locked into what POSIX deems a reasonable platform. Windows' locale support is not nearly as broken as C++', or POSIX' for that matter. Like, `setlocale()`, which you cannot reliably use in a multi-threaded environment, even if you tried. Unlike, say, [SetThreadLocale](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnls/nf-winnls-setthreadlocale). Neither POSIX nor C++ have a way to implement per-thread locale, all the while they are exposing `pthread`s and `std::thread`, respectively. Locales in C++ are built around broken assumptions. Don't use.

Comment: @IInspectable Why the heck would I want a per-program *or* per-thread locale? I want a locale object that is like any other object. Not a global implicit per-anything magic state. And of course `SetThreadLocale` does the same exact damn thing described in the question, only per thread instead of per process. Not a huge improvement.

Comment: @IInspectable I take it back. `SetThreadLocale` doesn't do the same thing. In fact it doesn't appear to do anything at all, as far as `printf` and friends are concerned. But the locale ID returned for `fre_fr` is invalid. It looks like this name is recognised by Python but not by Windows.

Comment: @IInspectable BTW I don't know why `std::moneypunct` is broken, can you enlighten me? Googling doesn't return anything useful.

Comment: *"Why the heck would I want a per-program or per-thread locale? I want a locale object that is like any other object. Not a global implicit per-anything magic state"* -  `printf()` doesn't take a locale as an input. What you would like to have or not have is of no relevance. `setlocale()` **must** use per-process global state in order for it to work. *"does the same exact damn thing described in the question, only per thread instead of per process. Not a huge improvement."* - The difference between having and not having the ability to write a correct program is quite significant, no?

Comment: *"`SetThreadLocale` doesn't do the same thing. In fact it doesn't appear to do anything at all, as far as printf and friends are concerned."* - Oh, of course not! It cannot possibly change the behavior of `printf()` and keep within what POSIX (or the C Standard) mandate. Either one mandates a broken design, that a system API cannot fix. *"I don't know why std::moneypunct is broken"* - [Binary Banshees and Digital Demons](https://thephd.dev/binary-banshees-digital-demons-abi-c-c++-help-me-god-please) explains why it is broken and why it cannot be fixed.

Comment: @IInspectable `printf` doesn't take locale as an input, which is bad, but I'm not using `printf`. Likewise, I'm not using `setlocale`. I am using C++ facilities. Why should broken C facilities concern me? I was only talking about them to demonstrate that they are not an improvement over what I'm trying to use. If your advice is to use SetThreadLocale and rewrite the rest of the program using Windows-specific functions because POSIX is broken, then I think I'll pass. I prefer working around (or living with) POSIX breakages over committing myself to a closed platform.

Comment: @IInspectable As for std::moneypunct, it seems the author is concerned about ABI breakage when a new virtual function is added. We have experienced an ABI breakage back in 2011. Does anyone remember it? ABI breakage is not such a big deal. We will survive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two separate problems.

1. `fre_fr` and `fr_FR.ISO8859-1` are not valid locale names as far as Windows is concerned. They are accepted by some third-party software (Python and maybe others) but one cannot use them in C `setlocale` or C++ `std::locale`. Weirdly, there seem to be two different failure modes when an invalid locale name is passed to the `std::locale` constructor. Sometimes it is silently interpreted exactly like a default user locale, and sometimes an exception is thrown. `xx_xx` and `fre_fr` are of the first kind, and `xxx_xxx` and `fr_FR.ISO8859-1` are of the second kind. I have no explanation for this.
2. `fr_fr` uses a non-ASCII thousands separator (a non-breaking space). Since the encoding used by this locale is Latin-1, it will break if the terminal is set up to handle UTF-8, because this character code is an incomplete/invalid UTF-8 sequence. `chcp 1252` solves the problem.